# Reproducing the standard layout of the "book" class with "titletoc"

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Is there a reference that shows how to use `titletoc` commands (`\titlecontents`, etc.) to approximate the layout of the table of contents in the standard `book` class?

In particular, I would like to see how to do this for the full range of sectioning commands, including `\part` and `\chapter`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, what you need this for, what you want to do? So far, the question hasn't seen much attention.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Often it happens that in general I like the layout of the standard table of contents, but I would just like to modify some particular detail (e.g., some details of the spacing, fonts, etc.). How do you do that with `titletoc`? If there was an example of how to reproduce the standard table of contents, then I could first just copy-paste that to my document, and then tweak it a bit.

Comment: Section 9.2 of the `titlesec` manual shows how to redefine the standard section commands. This is very helpful, I can just copy-paste it and then start tweaking it. With `titletoc` I haven't found anything similar. And with `titletoc` it is even worse, as the interface is much more complicated and there are more parameters to guess.

Comment: Ah, ok, now i understand it. Gimme a bit of time, never used `titletoc` before. Dunno, if i can find something reliable, either. But my question will also mention package `tocstyle`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any reference on how one would define the layout
of the standard classes using `titletoc`.

One place to look it up would be the class file itself, for a
chapter in the report and book class, we get the following definition.

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
     \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
     \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
     \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
     \begingroup
        \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
        \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
        \leavevmode \bfseries
        \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
        \hskip -\leftskip
        #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
        \penalty\@highpenalty
     \endgroup
  \fi}
```

After a bit of playing around, i still couldn't get any
satisfying result.

[image: jukkaToctitle]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1em}\bfseries}{\thecontentslabel\enspace}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{2pt}]
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\backmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

A package still in *alpha* but nevertheless very useful is
package `tocstyle` that does the hook approach `titletoc` wants to
prevent. This makes it relatively easy to change the appearance
for small parts only.

For example, if you want for very odd reason to have *just* the
pagenumbers larger and without serifs, you can do the following.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}
\settocfeature{pagenumberhook}{\Large\sffamily}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\backmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Good to demonstrate a point, but not for having in an own
document.

[image: jukkaTocstyle]

Answer (score 1):

For the `chapter` style in the ToC, the following code seems to reproduce the book class style slightly more accurately than the code by Johannes_B:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\titlecontents{chapter}
    [1.5em]
    {\addvspace{1em}\bfseries}
    {\contentslabel{1.3em}}
    {\hspace*{-1.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[.5pc]{}\contentspage}

% code by Johannes_B:
%\titlecontents{chapter}
%    [0pt]
%    {\vspace{1em}\bfseries}
%    {\thecontentslabel\enspace}
%    {}
%    {\hfill\contentspage}[\vspace{2pt}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\backmatter
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```